# XSLT: How to copy parent nodes unchanged and transform child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT, so this is probably very basic, but I would really appreciate some input. I need to transform the child nodes in my xml, but at the same time keep the parent nodes unchanged. My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XMLTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jfxpf="http://www.xfa.com/schema/xml-package" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.com/schema/xfa-data">
    <result form="10"   version="4" resultid="23146" respondent="ycisxmir" authid="" date="2012-09-12 06:39:44" times="462">
        <Q0061 answerid="1">1</Q0061>
        <Q0060 answerid="2">2</Q0060>
        <QTXT1>1</QTXT1>
    </result>
</XMLTest>
```

I need to keep the two top nodes XMLTest and result unchanged, whereas the child nodes need to be transformed to a more generic format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XMLTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jfxpf="http://www.xfa.com/schema/xml-package" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.com/schema/xfa-data">
    <result form="10"   version="4" resultid="23146" respondent="ycisxmir" authid="" date="2012-09-12 06:39:44" times="462">
        <answer>Q0061</answer>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>1</value>
        <answer>Q0060</answer>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>2</value>
        <answer>QTXT1</answer>
        <value>1</value>
    </result>
</XMLTest>
```

My xslt so far looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="result/*">
        <answer><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></answer> 
        <id><xsl:value-of select="@answerid"/></id> 
        <value><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></value> 
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried using xsl:copy on the top nodes, but can't make it work without losing the child nodes, or the transformation of the child nodes. How can I keep the top nodes and force through my transformed child nodes at the same time?

Comment: good try upvoted! just that You are missing identity template which copies rest other nodes.. Check my answer..

Comment: I have updated the answer with comments .. please check it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now add templates for the transformation you need i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="result/*[@answerid]">
        <answer><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></answer> 
        <id><xsl:value-of select="@answerid"/></id> 
        <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result/*[not(@answerid)]">
         <answer><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></answer> 
        <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: oh he doesn't need a blank node if no attribute .. ! +1

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I have corrected you answer..:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/XMLTest/result/*">
    <answer>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </answer>
    <id>
      <xsl:value-of select="@answerid"/>
    </id>
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
    </value>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit1:**
updated template to discard if attributes are null: an if condition checks if attribute is null before converting it to an element..

```
  <xsl:template match="/XMLTest/result/*">
    <answer>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </answer>
    <xsl:if test="@answerid/.!=''">
      <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="@answerid"/>
     </id>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@*/.!=''">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
    </value>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Edit2:** in ur early attempts, you were trying to copy value of @*, `@*` indicates Attribute of anyname, so it was copying value of @answerid (since that was the only attribute available).. what you had to do is .. `valu-of="."`.. please try the below code..

```
  <xsl:template match="/XMLTest/result/*">
    <answer>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </answer>
    <xsl:if test="@answerid/.!=''">
      <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="@answerid"/>
     </id>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=".!=''">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </value>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem! Just one detail which is still not right with the code. If the child node is missing the answerid attribute, the tag value does not get populated. How do I code this correctly? What I get is this: <answer>QTXT1</answer><id/><value/>.

Comment: Glad to know that .. yes what is it?? please go-head

Comment: @Chrissy, ohk that is easy, update the answer plz check. And let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: For <QTXT1>1</QTXT1> now I'm getting <answer>QTXT1</answer> and no value, instead of <answer>QTXT1</answer><value>1</value>. So somehow it is still not working?